# Proving $(n+1)!>2^{n+3}$ for all $n\geq 5$ by induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am stuck writing the body a PMI I have been working on for quite some time.

Theorem: $∀n∈N ≥ X$, $(n+1)!>2^{n+3}$

I will first verify that the hypothesis is true for at least one value of $n∈N$.

Consider $n=3$: (not valid)
$$(3+1)!>2^{3+3} \implies 4!>2^{6} \implies 24>64$$

Consider $n=4$: (not valid)
$$(4+1)!>2^{4+3} \implies 5!>2^{7} \implies 120>128$$

Consider $n=5$: (valid)
$$(5+1)!>2^{5+3} \implies 6!>2^{8} \implies 720>256$$

Consider $n=6$: (valid)
$$(6+1)!>2^{6+3} \implies 7!>2^{9} \implies 5040>512$$

So clearly $X$ is $5$.

For the inductive assumption, we will assume the hypothesis holes from $n=5$ up to some arbitrary values $k$: $(k+1)!>2^{k+3}$

*This is where I am lost. Originally I had written:*

Now I will prove true for $k+1$ showing that: $(k+2)!>2^{k+4}$. Consider the $k+1$ term:

$$(k+2)(k+1)k! = (k+2)(k+1)2^k = (k+2)(k+1)2^k = (2)(2)(2^k) = (4)(2^k) = 2^{k+4}$$
by the inductive assumption since $k>5$ so $k+1>2$ and $k+2>2$ but I know this isn't correct.

*I know the proof should look something like this, but I have no idea why:*

$$(k+2)(k+1)!>(k+2)(2^{k+3})>2(2^{k+3})=2^{k+4}$$

Comment: One of the main issues is that your proof is not very well-written (no offense). You need to make it clear what statement you are trying to prove (and for what values), where specifically you use the inductive hypothesis, etc. If you can clean it up a good bit, then I think you will have less confusion. My main point in answering was to provide you with a clean way of writing it up. I'd suggest following that sort of "template" in the future to make your inductive proofs clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq 5$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : (n+1)! > 2^{n+3}.
$$

**Base step $(n=5)$:** $S(5)$ says $6!>2^8$, and this is true since $720>256$.

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 5$ and suppose that 
$$
S(k) : (k+1)!>2^{k+3}
$$
is true. We must now prove that $S(k+1)$ follows where
$$
S(k+1) : (k+2)! > 2^{k+4}.
$$
Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
(k+2)! &= (k+1)!\cdot(k+2)\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&> 2^{k+3}(k+2)\tag{by $S(k)$}\\[0.5em]
&\geq 2^{k+3}\cdot 7\tag{since $k\geq 5$}\\[0.5em]
&> 2^{k+3}\cdot 2\\[0.5em]
&= 2^{k+4},
\end{align}
we see that the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$ follows. Thus, $S(k)\to S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

Thus, by mathematical induction, for all $n\geq 5$, the statement $S(n)$ is true. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

Your first two steps are correct. You have established that:$$(n+1)!\gt2^{n+3}$$is first true when $n=5$. You then correctly assumed that it holds for some $n=k\ge5$, giving you:$$(k+1)!\gt2^{k+3}\tag{1}$$And, finally you also proceeded in the right direction by then saying that you now need to prove that this implies it is also true for $n=k+1$. If we look at $n=k+1$ we get:$$(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1)!$$Now use the result from (1) to deduce that:$$(k+2)!\gt(k+2)2^{k+3}$$You can then show that:$$(k+2)2^{k+3}=k.2^{k+3}+2.2^{k+3}=k.2^{k+3}+2^{k+4}\gt2^{k+4}$$

Answer (score 2):

**First, show that this is true for $n=5$:**

$(5+1)!>2^{5+3}$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$(n+1)!>2^{n+3}$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$(n+2)!=\color{red}{(n+1)!}\cdot\color{blue}{(n+2)}>\color{red}{2^{n+3}}\cdot\color{blue}{(n+2)}>\color{red}{2^{n+3}}\cdot\color{blue}{2}=2^{n+4}$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure when you say "I have no idea why" what it is you are unsure about. That is precisely the right proof. The first inequality holds by the inductive hypothesis. The second holds because for $k\ge 5$ certainly $k+2>2$.

Comment: I'm assuming what the correct proof is doing is it's taking the left-hand expression of the $k+1$ term and manipulating it in such a way that the $k$ right-hand term can be substituted in. This will then be manipulated so it matches the right-hand expression. Is this what's going on? Is this a standard proof strategy?

Comment: Yes, it is how many inductive proofs like this work. Do you see why it proves the statement?

Comment: Yeah, I think so although I'm sure there's a more complex explanation as to why this procedure works compared to my base level of knowledge on this.

Comment: I think you are making it more complicated than it is :) You want to prove something about $(k+2)!$. So write down $(k+2)!$ and manipulate it so you get an expression [$(k+1)!$] that you already know something about. That process has very little to do with induction; it's just proof technique --- manipulating unknowns to get something you know.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ \dfrac{(n\!+\!1)!}{2^{n+3}}\, =\, \dfrac{n\!+\!1}2\ \dfrac{n}2\,\cdots\, \dfrac{7}2\ \dfrac{6!}{2^8}\ $ is a product of terms $> 1$ so, by induction, is $> 1$

**Remark** $\ $ The proof essentially uses *telescopy* to rewrite the expression as a product. As above, where we reduced the induction to the *trivial* induction that a product of terms $> 1$ stays $> 1$, telescopy often greatly simplifies such inductive proofs. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:242+telescopy) for many further examples.